# Meaning of multiple JDKs on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, java

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.4. My Java Preferences shows the following:
[image: Java Preferences]

If I run `locate javac`, I get:

```
...
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/javac
...
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Commands/javac
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
...
/usr/bin/javac
...
```

Where nothing seems to be soft-linking something else.

- If I have only one JDK, why are there multiple locations for this one command?
- What is the conceptual difference between `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/` and 
  `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`?
- Is there a single folder in Mac OS X that could be called "`JAVA_HOME`", that would contain all the JDK tools as well as header files (such as `jni.h`), similar to the way this is done in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I use `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home` as `JAVA_HOME`. That's the location of the JDK.

Comment: On my system, this links to `CurrentJDK`, which in turns links to `A`, which cannot really be considered a JDK - there is no `classes.jar`, the folder structure is weird (for example, `javac` should probably be in `JAVA_HOME/bin/javac`)...

Comment: Yes, it's the Apple's mess, there's no one-for-one equivalent to other distributions. My bin directory does contain javac, however (along the rest).

Comment: In this sense, `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home` looks much more like the "traditional" `JAVA_HOME` - but it has its problems as well - there is no `classes.jar` in `lib/` for starters.

Comment: I actually download the developer packages which installs JDKs to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`. I use those JDKs for JAVA_HOME.